# How do I stop a hittestobject from going into another frame? FLASH AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a drag and drop game with a hittestobject, but when pressing the back button the label of the drag and drop game are still shown up on the back frame. Do i have to reset the game before pressing the back button?

Code:

```
right_mc.visible=false; 
wrong_mc.visible=false;

var orig1X:Number=frog_mc.x;  
var orig1Y:Number=frog_mc.y;
var orig2X:Number=queen_mc.x;
var orig2Y:Number=queen_mc.y;
var orig3X:Number=apple_mc.x;
var orig3Y:Number=apple_mc.y; 

frog_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
frog_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, frog_mcRelease);
queen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);   
queen_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, queen_mcRelease);   
apple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);    
apple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, apple_mcRelease);    

done_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswers);    
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

frog_mc.buttonMode=true;    
queen_mc.buttonMode=true;    
apple_mc.buttonMode=true;

function dragTheObject(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.startDrag(); 
    var topPos:uint=this.numChildren-1; 
    this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);    
}  


function frog_mcRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.stopDrag();       
    if (drop_frog.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        item.x=drop_frog.x; 
        item.y=drop_frog.y; 
    } else { 
       item.x=orig1X; 
       item.y=orig1Y; 
    } 
};    

function queen_mcRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.stopDrag();   
    if (drop_queen.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        item.x=drop_queen.x; 
        item.y=drop_queen.y; 
    } else { 
        item.x=orig2X; 
        item.y=orig2Y; 
    } 
};    

function apple_mcRelease(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target); 
    item.stopDrag();   
    if (drop_apple.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) { 
        item.x=drop_apple.x; 
        item.y=drop_apple.y; 
    } else { 
        item.x=orig3X; 
        item.y=orig3Y; 
    } 
};  

function checkAnswers(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    if (drop_frog.hitTestPoint(frog_mc.x,frog_mc.y) && 
            drop_queen.hitTestPoint(queen_mc.x,queen_mc.y) && 
            drop_apple.hitTestPoint(apple_mc.x,apple_mc.y)) {
        wrong_mc.visible = false;
        right_mc.visible = true;
    } else {
        wrong_mc.visible = true;
        right_mc.visible = false;
    }
}

function reset(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    frog_mc.x=orig1X; 
    frog_mc.y=orig1Y;     
    queen_mc.x=orig2X; 
    queen_mc.y=orig2Y;
    apple_mc.x=orig3X; 
    apple_mc.y=orig3Y; 

    right_mc.visible=false; 
    wrong_mc.visible=false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to remove all eventListeners when you go back. And if you added some childs by addChild command of another one, you must remove chat childs. How did you added that "label of the drag and drop game" to screen?